# Obtaining the Möbius strip as a quotient of $S^1\times[-1,1]$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

I am trying to obtain the Möbius strip as a quotient of $S^1\times[-1,1]$, where $S^1$ is, of course, the circle.
My definition of Möbius strip is the quotient of the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ by the equivalence relation $(x,0)\sim(1-x,1)$.

I am searching for an identification $f$ between $S^1\times[-1,1]$ and $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and then I want to prove that $\sim_{p'\circ f}=\sim_p$ with $p(t)=[t]$ by the antipodal relation and $p'(t)=[t]$ by the Möbius strip's relation.

My problem is I can't find $f$.

Could I do it the other way, that is, find an identification between $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $S^1\times[-1,1]$?

Comment: Is it helpful to note that $S^1$ is $[0,1]$ with endpoints glued together?

Comment: Not really. I have tried that approach. Basically I think I am trying to reverse that argument

Comment: In your equivalence relation for $x=1/2$ we have $(1/2,0) \sim (1/2,1)$. In your square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ this line $(1/2,t)$ for $t\in [0,1]$ represents your $S^1$.

Comment: shouldn't the relation be $(x,0)\sim(-x,1)$?

Answer (score 6):

We can construct the quotient directly by identifying 
$$(z,-1)\sim \left(\frac{1}{z},1\right)$$
We can see that this works correctly by noting that if we map $[0,1]\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{S}^1\times [-1,1]$ via the function 
$$(x,y)\mapsto (e^{2\pi i (x-\frac{1}{2})},2(y-\frac{1}{2}))$$
then the identification $(x,0)\sim (1-x,1)$ is translated to 
$$(e^{2\pi i (x-\frac{1}{2})},-1)\sim (e^{2\pi i (\frac{1}{2}-x)},1)$$
and this coincides with the definition $(z,-1)\sim \left(\frac{1}{z},1\right)$.

EDIT: Note that there is no way to obtain a Mobius strip from $\mathbb{S}^1\times [-1,1]$ by identifying opposite edges. The space constructed here is homeomorphic to the Klein bottle.

We obtain the Mobius strip by identifying $(z,x)\sim (-z,-x)$. To see this, map $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]\to \mathbb{S}^1\times [-1,1]$ by sending $(x,y)\mapsto (e^{\pi i x},y)$. When we identify $(z,x)\sim (-z,-x)$, we are identifying $(e^{\pi i x},y)\sim (e^{\pi i (x+1)},-y)$. Thus if $x<0$ we have $(x,y)\sim (x+1,-y)$. Map the quotient space to the Mobius strip, considered as the quotient of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ by identifying $(0,y)\sim (1,1-y)$, by sending $[(x,y)]\mapsto [(x+1,\frac{1}{2}(1+y))]$ for $x\leq 0$. Verify that this is a homeomorphism between the quotient space and the Mobius strip.

Comment: That would work but I am trying to do it with the antipodal relation.

Comment: Maybe we are talking about diferent things.

Comment: By antipodal I mean, for example, $(1,0)\in S^1 \sim (-1,0)\in S^1$

Comment: @user203327 The antipodal map won't work because it is homotopic to the identity.

Comment: The exercise says that. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @user203327 Do you mean to construct the Klein bottle? Whether or not we agree on the antipodal map being the correct identification, if you use my map you get the Klein bottle and if you use the identity map you get a torus.

Comment: I was trying for the Möbius strip. I put the cylinder that way so the relation would be that $x\sim -x$, which I think it is the antipodal

Comment: @user203327 If this is from an exercise, it would be helpful if you could post the details of the exercise.

Comment: The exercise says: Obtain the Möbius strip as a quotient of the cilinder by the antipodal relation.

Comment: @user203327 I see what it meant, it's identification $(z,y)\sim (-z,-y)$ across the whole cylinder. The new edit handles that.